# What is this object property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oop, properties

My tool generated a code from XML and inside I can see this, but cannot understand it

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request", typeof(RequestType), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Response", typeof(ResponseType), Order = 0)]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.itemField != null))
            {
                if ((itemField.Equals(value) != true))
                {
                    this.itemField = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.itemField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }
    }
```

Why the type is object and later how to know what type it is to proceed with?

Comment: You probably did something in your XSD which does not translate well to C#... check the elements with names "Request" and "Response". Ask yourself: How should the code be generated? How can I change the XSD so the generated code becomes more object-oriented?

Comment: Also, please post the XSD...

Comment: Are you using that for calling a web service?

Comment: Yes, I cannot change the XSD

Answer (score 2):

What the code means is that `Item` can take an object of type `RequestType` or `ResponseType` and will be serialized/deserialized as `RequestType` or `ResponseType`. It is purely down to the way XSD is designed.

In your case, I think the `Request` or `Response` element in the XML is part of another element. When to use `Request` and when to use `Response` is purely dynamic. A sample request going to the web service could be as below

```
<root>
<header>
</header>
<request>
....
</request>
</root>
```

and a sample response from the web service can be as below

```
<root>
<header>
</header>
<response>
....
</response>
</root>
```

and your generated reference/proxy class could be like

```
public partial class Root {

public Header HeaderValue {
get { ... }
set { ... }
}

// then the item object
public object Item {
get { ... }
set { ... }
} 

}
```

When constructing your request, you'll be aware upfront on which object type to use. ex. it will be the `Request` object type. So your code will be something like

```
Root root = new Root();
RequestType requestType = new RequestType();
requestType.someProperty = someValue;
...
objRoot.Item = requestType;
```

When it serializes it goes out with the `Request` element. Same case when it comes back from the web service where the type will be `Response`.